# AttributeError: Packagings instance has no attribute 'flute'

Tags: python, attributes

```
class Packagings:
    def _init_(self):
        self.length,self.deckle,self.tmp,self.flute,self.gsm,self.t_weight,self.weight

    def read_values(self):
        print """Select Type Of Paper
               1.3 Ply
               2.5 Ply
               3.7 Ply
               """
        self.type=input("Enter the type:")
        self.l=input("Enter Length:")
        self.b=input("Enter Breadth:")
        self.h=input("Enter Height:")
        self.flap=input("Enter Flap:")


    def ply_read_values(self):
        for i in range(0,3):
            self.flute[i]=input("Enter flute:")
            self.gsm[i]=input("Enter Gsm:")
            self.weight[i]=self.tmp*(flute[i]*gsm[i])
            self.t_weight=self.t_weight+self.weight[i]

    def do_calc(self):
        self.length=(2*self.l+2*self.b+self.flap)/1000
        self.deckle=(float(self.h+self.b))/1000
        self.tmp=self.length*self.deckle


    def print_value(self):
        print self.length
        print self.deckle
        print self.t_weight

#Main Function
obj=Packagings()
obj.read_values()
obj.do_calc()
obj.ply_read_values()
obj.print_value()
```

I get the following error when I try to run the program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/packagings.py", line 41, in <module>
    obj.ply_read_values()
  File "C:/Python27/packagings.py", line 21, in ply_read_values
    self.flute[i]=input("Enter flute:")
AttributeError: Packagings instance has no attribute 'flute'
```

Is there any specific way to use lists inside the python program? I think the error is due to me using lists in the wrong way. Can you go through the code and tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What are you trying to do with this line ? :

```
class Packagings:
    def _init_(self):      # first, I suppose you wanted to write __init__ as @larsmans noticed in comment
        self.length,self.deckle,self.tmp,self.flute,self.gsm,self.t_weight,self.weight
```

if you don't affect them to something, those members will never exist.

Try this instead :

```
class Packagings:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.deckle = 0.0
        self.tmp = 0.0
        self.flute = []
        self.gsm = []
        self.t_weight = 0
        self.weight = 0
```

Comment: ... and rename `_init_` to `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

As larsmans said, you have to replace

```
def _init_(self):
```

by

```
def __init__(self):
```

In your code init is never called, so your array is never created.

Then, look at Cédric Julien's post to see how to create corectly your atributes

Comment: Note that if the OP had correctly spelled `__init__`, that function would have raised the `AttributeError`.